# Arched coloring of graph: $A(D) \ge \log \chi(D)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $D$ be a directed graph. Arched coloring of $D$ is any coloring of edges such that $$ \forall_{a,b} (a,b) \mbox{ and } (b,c) $$
have different colors for any $(a,b), (b,c) \in E(D) $. A(D) is the smallest number of colors on which we can arche color $D$. Proof that
$$ A(D) \ge \log \chi(D) $$

### Idea

I have drawn $K_4$ and had idea that I can color each vertex with color:
$$0,1,2,...,\chi(G)-1$$
and then color $(a,b)$ on $color(a)+color(b) \mod \lceil\log\chi(G)\rceil $. And for $K_n$ it seems to work. But I have just checked that way on very small example like path $P_3$.  $\chi(P_3) = 2$ and colors will be $0,1,0$ so colors of path will be just $1$ and $1$ so it is wrong.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: @saulspatz I have just  edited

Comment: Does $\log$ mean the natural logarithm?  Also, your definition talks about coloring the arcs, but in your examples see to be coloring the vertices.  I don't understand.

Comment: log means $log_2$. My exaple uses vertex coloring to define edge coloring @saulspatz

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.  Somehow I read right over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show that $A(D) \ge \log \chi(D)$, then the natural strategy is to use an arc-coloring of $D$ with $A(D)$ colors to define a vertex-coloring of $D$ with $2^{A(D)}$ colors (getting an upper bound on $\chi(D)$). Even if you succeeded in going the other way, using a vertex coloring to define an arc-coloring, you would get the reverse inequality.

One way to rephrase the condition for a proper arc-coloring is that for every vertex $v$ and for every color $c$, there cannot be both an edge *into* $v$ and en edge *out of* $v$ given the color $c$.

Given this observation (and an arc-coloring of $D$ with $A(D)$ colors), a natural labeling of the vertices of $D$ with $2^{A(D)}$ values is to give each vertex $v$ a label $f(v) \in \{-1,1\}^{A(D)}$ where:

- $f_i(v) = -1$ if all edges of color $i$ incident to $v$ are oriented into $v$.
- $f_i(v) = +1$ if all edges of color $i$ incident to $v$ are oriented out of $v$.
- $f_i(v)$ is arbitrary if there are no edges of color $i$ incident to $v$.

Now we just check that this is a proper coloring. If $(v,w)$ is any edge, let $i$ be its color. Then $f_i(v) = +1$, because the edge $(v,w)$ has color $i$ and is oriented out of $v$, and $f_i(w) = -1$, because the edge $(v,w)$ has color $i$ and is oriented into $w$. Therefore $f(v) \ne f(w)$.

Comment: In other words, the color of a vertex $v$ is the set of all colors of edges leaving $v$.